the signature module size changes from 4096 bits to 1024 bits after uploading the APK to the Play Store,
develpoer shared built with me as a tester analisise a source code found module size is 1024  i reported them but team is unable to fix the issue they shared me uat apk the apk have 4096 size but after uploading to play store and downlaoded a apk check sourceenter image description here code it again become 1024 module size
please help me to metigate this vunerability

Do you upload an APK to Play store or an app bundle? If it is the latter the signature is only the upload signature and Google will sign it with your real signing key (stored in Google Cloud) after generating the various optimized split APK files. If you want to change the signing key this can be triggered at Google but it will only affect newer devices as key updating doesn't work with older Android versions.

can you explain to me how can i mitigate this type of issue

The process is pretty complicated even if it is managed by Google. You should better read about it before deciding to go this way: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?visit_id=638487071422834819-3520295072&rd=1#upgrade
